# How to resolve a Taurus throwing a loader error?

Tags: windows, yaml, taurus, bzt

I need to run the taurus software on windows, and it looks like I am at the end of knowledge about that, and need help from you.

This is the line:
`C:\tools\....\bzt.exe -o modules.cloud.token=**** taurus/test.yaml -cloud`

And this is the error:

```
14:54:37 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.4.2
14:54:37 INFO: Starting with configs: ['taurus/test.yaml']
14:54:37 INFO: Configuring...
14:54:37 INFO: No personal config: C:\.....\.bzt-rc
14:54:37 ERROR: TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'
14:54:37 WARNING: Please wait for graceful shutdown...
14:54:37 INFO: Post-processing...
14:54:37 INFO: Artifacts dir: None
14:54:37 WARNING: Done performing with code: 1
14:54:37 WARNING: Artifacts dir has not been set, will not copy bzt.log
```

So Specifically this:

```
ERROR: TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'
```

This is my test.yaml file:

```
execution:
  concurrency: 10
  hold-for: 2m30s
  ramp-up: 1m

scenarios:
  scenario1:
    requests:
      - label: blazedemo
        method: GET
        url: http://blazedemo.com/
```

I checked the version of taurus, it's now 1.4.2, I upgraded to the newest version, and it threw the same error.
I checked the python version, it's 3.8.7 (compatible with my taurus version)
I tried different yaml and yml files
Token is correct, I can run the same line without the token.
All threw the same error.

What should I do?
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a version issue, I am running with Pyyaml 6.0.1
I downgraded it to 5.4.X, and the issue was resolved.

Also, as an additional note, it looks like that taurus is not expecting to get a file such as the one I posted in the question, insted, it insists that each taurus file using yaml starts with 3 dashes (---), otherwise it wont recognize it as a separate file, and will throw a file not found exception.